# localization for Permalink

Tags: permalinks, localization, language

Originally, wordpress creates permalink like **/2013/07/**  , **/archives/123**
here I want to localize with my native numeric numbers .
is it possible to do like that ?

Comment: The answer is yes, what is the real question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under permalink settings you want to use `Custom Structure` you can then customise it using the structure tags see http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags this would allow you to add post id and author to the permalink for example.

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/%postid%/%author%/
```

All depending on what you need if you can be more specific about what you mean by native numbers this answer can be expanded.